# Prevent body scroll on click and close of overlay menu css

Tags: javascript, css, menu, overlay

Currently I have an overlay CSS menu that is initiated through a click. However the page behind it is still scrollable. I'm sure this is a simple fix, but i'm new to css/js and any help would be great!

Currently I have a js toggle function that when .icon (hamburger icon) is hit the .mobilenav (overlay menu) is faded over the page.

What kind of function can I add to prevent body scrolling once this toggle function is enabled?

Anything I can easily add to this function below?

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".icon, .link").click(function () {
        $(".mobilenav").fadeToggle(700);
        $(".top-menu").toggleClass("top-animate");
        $(".mid-menu").toggleClass("mid-animate");
        $(".bottom-menu").toggleClass("bottom-animate");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess you are looking for something like this:

```
document.body.style.overflow="hidden"
```

And to be able to scroll again, use

```
document.body.style.overflow="scroll"
```

Example:

```js
document.body.onclick=function(){
  this.style.overflow="hidden"
}
```

```html
Click anywhere to disable scrolling<hr>
Click anywhere to disable scrolling<hr>
Click anywhere to disable scrolling<hr>
Click anywhere to disable scrolling<hr>
Click anywhere to disable scrolling<hr>
Click anywhere to disable scrolling<hr>
Click anywhere to disable scrolling<hr>
Click anywhere to disable scrolling<hr>
Click anywhere to disable scrolling<hr>
Click anywhere to disable scrolling<hr>
Click anywhere to disable scrolling<hr>
Click anywhere to disable scrolling<hr>
Click anywhere to disable scrolling<hr>
Click anywhere to disable scrolling<hr>
Click anywhere to disable scrolling<hr>
Click anywhere to disable scrolling<hr>
Click anywhere to disable scrolling<hr>
Click anywhere to disable scrolling<hr>
Click anywhere to disable scrolling<hr>
Click anywhere to disable scrolling<hr>
```

Also, as you are using jQuery, something like this would work too:

```
$('body').css('overflow', 'hidden'); // disables scrolling
$('body').css('overflow', 'scroll'); // enables scrolling
```

Comment: Just added a snippet of my js function for the toggle. Anything I can add to  that to enable those functions you said above?

Comment: @Nir Is it really difficult to do it yourself? Or it is a homework and you don't have an idea what you are doing? I provided you a way, showed you en example.

Comment: Awesome, sorry I'm just very new to this, so I'm a little confused. I am able to get the scroll to stop, but once a link is clicked or the overlay is closed, the body is still stuck on overflow hidden. How do i add scroll back to the body once an action has taken place? Thanks!

Comment: @Nir Which action exactly?

Comment: So I added the  `$('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');` to the jQuery function, but i'd like to go back to overflow=scroll once the user either clicks on a nav link or hits the icon again.

Comment: @Nir so what's the problem to add it to `$(".icon, .link").click()`?

Comment: I may just sound stupid, but i don't know how to add that back on to the function.

Comment: Ok so I know how to add it, but i don't know how to remove 'hidden' once it's enabled. Basically when the overlay menu is now enabled the body does not scroll with this `$('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');` but let's say they user is done with the menu, now the body is still stuck with 'hidden'. How do i toggle between the two when a link or icon is clicked?

Comment: @Nir what do you have?

Comment: no luck either. Not sure how the if/else statement works in this case. may need a separate function. I guess I'm trying to figure out from a logical standpoint how to remove a function that is added on the 'second' click. Like we are enabling overflow= hidden on the first click, but how do we disable it once it's clicked out?

Comment: ok I have a few more questions you can maybe help me with. 1) I realized I originally had overflow-x: hidden, but removed it for the jQuery function to work, now i realize I need overflow-x to be hidden always. I tried to adjust the jquery function to account only for overflow-y, but nothing seems to work :/ 2) also, how would i make this work with mobile?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".icon, .link").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('body').toggleClass('overflow');
            $(".mobilenav").fadeToggle(700);
            $(".top-menu").toggleClass("top-animate");
            $(".mid-menu").toggleClass("mid-animate");
            $(".bottom-menu").toggleClass("bottom-animate");
        });
    });

   Add the below piece of code into css file

  .overflow
  {
     overflow:hidden;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this but to no luck. The background is still scrollable. Any ideas?